# Pandas rolling group by sum

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, rolling-computation

I have a pandas `dataframe`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Name':['John', 'John', 'John', 'Jill', 'Jill', 'Jill', 'Jill'],'Score':[1,1, 1,2,2, 2, 2]})

df
Out[168]: 
   Name  Score
0  John      1
1  John      1
2  John      1
3  Jill      2
4  Jill      2
5  Jill      2
6  Jill      2
```

I want to add a column that contains the rolling sum of the previous 2 values in a column (column `score` here) like so:

```
Out[171]: 
   Name  Score  Total
0  John      1      1
1  John      1      2
2  John      1      2
3  Jill      2      2
4  Jill      2      4
5  Jill      2      4
6  Jill      2      4
```

I have tried `groupby` and `rolling` which works but the row order is not the same as the original `dataframe`. Notice how `Jill` is now first, probably due to some alphabetical sorting:

```
df.groupby('Name')['Score'].rolling(2, min_periods=1).sum()
Out[173]: 
Name   
Jill  3    2.0
      4    4.0
      5    4.0
      6    4.0
John  0    1.0
      1    2.0
      2    2.0
Name: Score, dtype: float64
```

How does this work and how can I achieve the goal without doing a leftjoin / merge afterwards?

Comment: `df.groupby('Name',sort=False)['Score'].rolling(2, min_periods=1).sum()` ? tell groupby not to sort

Comment: @anky + `.reset_index(name='Total')` at the end

Comment: @anky that does it